# What is the purpose of path in ezpublish module?

Tags: ezpublish

What is the purpose of `path` in module result? 
https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/3.8/Templates/The-pagelayout/Variables-in-pagelayout

Is it for getting a different path in page layout than the actual path?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `path` property in module result is, in most of the cases, to generate breadcrumbs. It contains an array of `breadcrumb node` needed to build the HTML links which are part of your breadcrumb.

Each item of this array is also an array containing at least the following key :

- `text` : used for the innerHTML part of the `<a>` tag
- `url` : used for the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag

`url` might be `false` and it's often the case when you are on the last item which basically means that you will display the name of that `breadcrumb node` but you don't want to create a link for it, since you are already on the related page...

For built-in modules, eZ Publish always provides the `$module_result.path` variable on the pagelayout. In addition to that, when you are viewing a content, it will also provide the url_alias (`/Folder/Article` for instance) which is better than the 'system url' of the content (`/content/view/full/123` for instance).

If you want to provide such information for your custom modules, you just need to return it at the end of your controller (in `extension/myextension/modules/myviewcontroller.php` for instance) :

```php
<?php
// ....
$Result['path'] = array(
    array('text'=>'My custom module','url'=>'/mymodule/myview'),
    array('text'=>'My view','url'=>false),
);
```